# How to use $watch in angularjs component

Tags: angularjs

I am using jCarousel for image thumbnail slider. but previously I was using directive for the same but now I changed my code to component. but now I am not able to use that link function and watch reload in component. because I am using first time component in agularjs.

//Previous code

```
directive('jblogcarousel', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        jitems: "="
    },
    templateUrl: '/templates/blog-carousel.html',

    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var container = $(element);
    var carousel = container.find('.jcarousel');

    carousel.jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
    });

    scope.$watch(attrs.jitems, function (value) {
        carousel.jcarousel('reload');
    });

    container.find('.jcarousel-control-prev')
        .jcarouselControl({
        target: '-=1'
    });

    container.find('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .jcarouselControl({
        target: '+=1'
    });
  }
};
```

});

//Current code

```
.component('jCarousel', {
bindings: {
    jitems: '='
},
templateUrl: '/templates/carousel.html'
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, in Angular 1.5 components `bindings` will bind the value to the controller.

So you can add a controller (with a `$watch` inside):

```
// bindings: { ... },
// templateUrl: '...',
controller: function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    console.log(vm.jitems); // vm.jitems should exist and be bound the value you passed to the component from the outside

    // you should be able to watch this value like this
    $scope.$watch(
        function () { return vm.jitems; },
        function (newValue) { console.log(newValue); }
    );
}
```

Also, with components, you should in most situations use one way binding `'<'` instead of two-way binding `'='`, and use functions/events (binding `'&'`) for the other direction.